# Set some word with highlight color in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

If I want to highlight some words in my doc in Emacs, how can I do it.

For example I have a log file where I recorded some daily information. And I want to make all "TODO" in this log be highlighted.

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at this thread :

[How to highlight all occurrences of a word in an Emacs buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385661/emacs-highlight-all-occurences-of-a-word)

This blog entry also describes a simple way to do it :

http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2008/12/highlighting-todo-fixme-and-friends.html

The best way to implement this depends on what you want exactly : you can toggle highlighting manually, or create a hook that will do it for any mode.