# Lightweight editor for Mac that highlights all occurrences of a word

Tags: macos, editor, notepad++, highlighting

My question is similar to this one: [How to highlight all occurrences of a word in an Emacs buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385661/emacs-highlight-all-occurences-of-a-word)

In Notepad++ editor, there's a convenient feature: if you select a word in your text (not necessarily a keyword), the word is highlighted throughout the text. Is there any similar way in a lightweight editor for Mac?  I've tried Textwrangler and jedit, but they don't seem to have this very useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the tips. I've tried out the various alternatives and ended up finding that jEdit has a good plugin for this feature: The "Highlight (Buffer scope)" option in the "Highlight" plugi

Comment: Yes, jEdit is a great text editor! Thanks for leading me to this plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

The only Mac text editor I know of that does this is Xcode, but I wouldn't exactly describe this as "lightweight".

Comment: Eclipse will do it to assuming the word is a var/method/class.

Answer (score 0):

You could to this in TextMate - not out of the box - but you could implement it fairly easily with whatever scripting language youre good with (ruby is whats normally used). There might even already be a plugin/bundle in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how willing you are, but you can look into writing a highlight plug-in for textWrangler.
I think you'll need the BBE-sdk. Here's their blurb on developing plugins: http://www.barebones.com/support/develop/

Answer (score 0):

vim, running in a Terminal is very lightweight and will do this.

```
vim file.txt
:set hlsearch
/word
```

If you only like GUI apps there is MacVim out there for downloading.