# Emacs: TODO indicator on left fringe has a strange side-effect - deleting characters

Tags: emacs

I just read [Emacs :TODO indicator at left side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242572/emacs-todo-indicator-at-left-side), and tried it out.  It seems intriguing.  The little indicator triangles appear, but I'm getting a weird side effect: the text itself is being altered.  Characters are being deleted.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

The mode-line does indicate that the buffer has been altered after running `annotate-todo`. 
What explains this?

(I'm using emacs 22.2.1 on Windows)

Comment: They weren't actually deleted, just displayed differently.  Which is nearly as icky.  I can't believe I didn't notice that side effect when I first made the solution.  I believe the new one works as you would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahhh... I see the error of my ways earlier.  Here's a new version.

```
(defun annotate-todo ()
  "put fringe marker on TODO: lines in the curent buffer"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "TODO:" nil t)
      (let ((overlay (make-overlay (- (point) 5) (point))))
        (overlay-put overlay 'before-string (propertize (format "A")
                                                        'display '(left-fringe right-triangle)))))))
```

The first solution used a the `'display` text property, which changes how the specified text is displayed, in this case it was *replaced* by the triangle in the [left fringe](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Margins.html#Display-Margins).  What I needed to do was to use a `'before-string` [*overlay*](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlays.html#Overlays) instead.  Which doesn't change the string being displayed.

Another advantage, the cut/paste of the code annotated by this does not carry the markup.

I've updated the code in the original question to reflect this change as well.