# highlight selected text in emacs (org-mode)

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am searching for a way to highlight selected text in Emacs permanently, just like you do with a marker in a PDF for example.  I am using org-mode.

I tried searching on Google but was quite surprised that I didn't find anything.

Comment: This is not a programming question, is it? It should therefore be posted in superuser.com, not here.

Comment: sounds logically, but arent most questions about emacs like this one? and there are quiet a lot of them on this site.

Comment: Also, emacs can be used for programming tasks. But using org-mode is not a programming task, or at least not specific to programming.

Comment: if emacs does not provide this funcionality, maybe i will add it ;)

Comment: OK, then: emacs does not provide this functionality for org-mode files.

Comment: are you sure about that, and does this apply for emacs in genral ? i can hardly believe this.

Comment: Emacs is a text editor, not a word processor like Microsoft Word. Although emacs has an optional GUI, inside the actual text editor part of the user interface it's basically just a text editor. It does have the ability to display images, but this is not a core focus of emacs development.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming as described in the FAQ.

Comment: i am not talking about highlights beeing a core focus, but a nice-to-have feature someone added

Comment: sorry for being off-topic, but i dont want to delete this question, or user2708138 will lose his reputation on this question, and it is in fact a good answer.

Comment: Hmmm. Reading SO [on-topic page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (again), I don't think this question is off-topic. The question is about *software tools commonly used by programmers*, and as far as I see, it is related to the programmable nature of Emacs.

Comment: i really appreciate how some people participate on this site. thank you all. <br> in the end its about providing information, itsn't it? and i think this question and especially the answers are useful to the community :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In org-mode you can use `*word*` to get `word` in bold face, `/word/` to get `word` in italics and `_word_` to get word underlined.

You can re-define the characters for emphasizing via `Options->Customize Emacs->Specific Option` then input `org-emphasis-alist`.

That is permanent in the sense that if you save and kill the buffer and reload the file into emacs you have the same high-lighting again.

Another way is to use enriched-mode. Input `M-x enriched-mode`. If `font-lock-mode` is **not** activated you can use stuff like `Edit->Text Properties->Face->Bold` and the formatting is permanent in the text-file.
It is clear that this leaves traces in the text file. You can see these traces if you load the file via `M-x find-file-literally`.

Note, that for easier formatting in the X11-port (I think also in the win32-port) you can detach the menus by clicking on the broken line on top (see the right side of the following image for two of such detached menus).

`font-lock-mode` re-fontifies text with rules from parameters like `font-lock-keywords` automatically and removes all other fontification (these parameters are most often set by the major-mode). Therefore, text properties do not work if `font-lock-mode` is activated. `org-mode` uses `font-lock-mode`, and text properties from `Edit->Text Properties->Face->Bold` cannot be used with `org-mode` (the corresponding menu items are deactivated). You can check whether `font-lock-mode` is active with <kbd>C-h m</kbd>. It is active if `Font-Lock` is listed. Alternatively, you can query <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `font-lock-mode` which is `t` if `font-lock-mode` is active.
[image: Fontified text in enriched-mode]

Comment: the answer is getting better and better :)

Comment: Indeed. You might want to check out [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903137/emacs-persistent-highlighting-of-a-region).

Comment: It's nice to know enriched-mode, but after `M-x enriched-mode`, the menu in `Edit->Text Properties->Face...` of my Emacs is impossible to be enabled, it's grey, both in normal `emacs` or `emacs -q`, I googled, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @CodyChan Works fine for me with `emacs -Q`. The command `emacs -q` loads the customization file `site-start.el` if one exists within your `load-path`. My emacs-version is: `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7) of 2014-03-07 on toyol, modified by Debian`.

Comment: @Tobias not work for me even in `emacs -Q` emacs-version:`GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.14.5) of 2014-11-19 on buildvm-13.phx2.fedoraproject.org`, OS: `Fedora 21(3.17.4-301.fc21.i686+PAE)`. I download tar file from Gnus page and extract and execute the binary with `-Q`, it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @CodyChan Note, that a disabled face menu might be a sign for activated `font-lock-mode`. You might test it with `M-x font-lock-mode`.

Comment: @Tobias yes, `font-lock-mode` is the problem. I already found the solution without using `enriched-mode`(since I always enable `font-lock-mode`). Add color to the `bold` markup in `org-emphasis-alist` would be better.

Comment: @CodyChan I added a note on `font-lock-mode`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use some commands from `hi-lock-mode`:

- `highlight-regexp` will ask you for a regexp to highlight and a color (there are some combinations of background and foreground)
- `highlight-lines-matching-regexp` does what it means
- you can enable or disable it with `hi-lock-mode`

and you can permanently save them with `hi-lock-write-interactive-patterns` (`M-s h w`). Emacs will write a bit of lisp in a commented line in your buffer.

See more tricks here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html

http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/10/13/highlighting-by-word-line-regexp/

Enjoy !