# Loading fic-mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, todo

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367611/emacs-highlighting-todo-only-in-comments/3900056#3900056) gave me the solution I needed. The only problem for me, is that I have to load it, namely `fic-mode`, manually. More explicitly, whenever I open a `c++` file, I have to do `M-x fic-mode` and then `M-x font-lock-fontify-buffer` in order to have it really up and running. In my `.emacs` I have

```
(require 'fic-mode)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook '(lambda () (fic-mode 1)))
```

but it doesn't do the trick.

Do you have any suggestions how to make it available automatically?

Comment: That looks reasonable to me. Check the `*Messages*` for error messages, and if you don't see any, double-check that your C++ files are actually getting opened in C++ mode: `C-h m`

Comment: seems like moving around the `fic-mode` related part in my `.emacs` solved the issue. This is very vague solution... but it worked.

Comment: A stupid question: are you sure that your buffer is in c++-mode?

Comment: @Thomas: As far as I can tell, then yes. At the bottom I can see a `C++` indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: create a new file containing the following three lines:

```
(setq load-path (cons "/path/to/fic-mode-directory" load-path))
(require 'fic-mode)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'turn-on-fic-mode)
```

Replace `"/path/to/fic-mode-directory"` with the absolute path to the directory in which you saved `fic-mode.el`.

Then from the command line, run

```
emacs -Q -l /path/to/file
```

where `/path/to/file` is the path to the above file.

Now type <kbd>C-x C-f test.cpp</kbd>.

Is fic-mode turned on in the resulting buffer?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that you already found a work-around. Perhaps you should close the question then.