# Highlighting TODOs in all programming modes

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

What is the root mode I need to hook to highlight TODOs in Ruby, Lisp, and C-like languages. I tried the following, but it doesn't highlight TODO in Ruby or Lisp:

```
(defun highlight-todos (font-lock-add-keywords nil
             '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\|TODO\\|BUG\\):" 1 font-lock-warning-face t))))
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'highlight-todos)
```

Comment: The likely problem with this code is that the TODOs lie within comment regions, and comments are typically identified and fontified using the syntax tables for the active mode; your font-lock keywords don't get chance to be applied, because the region has already been marked as a comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs: highlighting TODO *only* in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367611/emacs-highlighting-todo-only-in-comments)

Answer (score 6):

I think to get it to all programming modes to work use `prog-mode-hook`

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'highlight-todos)
```